# Trying to install php's gd extension

Tags: 20.04, php, gnupg

I'm trying to install gd extension, but getting error while adding repository

```
WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 
  688, in addkey_func
  func(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
  return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 252, in 
  add_ppa_signing_key
tmp_keyring, tmp_secret_keyring, signing_key_fingerprint, tmp_keyring_dir):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 181, in _recv_key
  "--recv", signing_key_fingerprint,
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
  with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gpg': 'gpg'
```

If `apt update` getting this error

```
    Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jczaplicki/xenial-php74-temp/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jczaplicki/xenial-php74-temp/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Hit:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jczaplicki/xenial-php74-temp/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Details are incomplete. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't tell us the actions you are taking. Include in your question the commands you are using and the entire output of each command. Do not give us partial command output. That being said, if I had to guess, your package management is broken. If I had to guess further, it's because you have invalid or outdated PPAs or other sources. Suggested reading: [Are PPAs safe?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu? Debian is off topic here.

Comment: It's docker container inside Ubuntu 20.04, first I try to install gd extension
 `apt-get install php7.4-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-gd' `
Then after commands in task, nothing else

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't use add comment because you can't format properly and there isn't enough room to add detailed information. If you're using Ubuntu, then why do you have Debian sources?

Comment: Bro, If I knew, I wouldn't be writing here.
I used this 3 command and that's all

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. If you knew what? What is the "3 command"? Please edit your question and keep it up-to-date. If you're using Debian, this question needs to be closed as off topic. If you're using Ubuntu, make sure that your question contains enough information to answer. If your question contains little more that terminal output without even giving us the command that produces the output, then you don't have enough information. Add enough details and context that someone will be able to answer. See: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15152 for tips on writing a good question

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/q/866901

Comment: What information is needed to answer?

Comment: Start by answering the questions I asked in comments and filling in the missing information I mentioned in comments. Read the links I posted and edit your question accordingly.